# wallet connect button integration using web3Modal

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, react, polygon

I'm trying to integrate wallet connect to my dApp using web3modal.
Link to the docs -> https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/react/installation

The dApp is about token swapping.
When I try to start the server, I'm facing below error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@web3modal/ethereum/dist/index.js 17:13
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:13)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     const n = this.wagmi.connectors.find(o => o.id === "walletConnect"),
|       t = this.wagmi.connectors.find(o => o.id === "walletConnectLegacy"),
>       e = n ?? t;
|     if (!e) throw new Error("WalletConnectConnector or WalletConnectLegacyConnector is required");
|     return {
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-dapp-metamask-connect",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.19.6",
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.0.14",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.6.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fontsource/inter": "^4.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@wagmi/core": "^0.10.11",
    "@web3modal/ethereum": "^2.4.1",
    "@web3modal/html": "^2.3.7",
    "@web3modal/react": "^2.4.1",
    "alchemy-sdk": "^2.8.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "ethers": "^5",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "recharts": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "viem": "^0.3.41",
    "wagmi": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I checked few online solutions for babel-loader but nothing seems to work in this case.
Any help would be appreciated.